# How to Reproduce Same Result Using Conv2d in Tensorflow.Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I read many posts on Stack Overflow as well Github on this topic, but I think my situation might be little different.

My code starts like below, and I can consistently reproduce the result 100% if I only use Dense layer.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rn
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
np.random.seed(1)
rn.seed(2)
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
tf.set_random_seed(3)
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess)
```

However, every time I run, I get different results if I insert this one line "model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'))" before "model.add(Flatten())".

Input> flatten > dense produces consistent result, but input > conv2d > flatten > dense produces different result every time I run the code.

I'd appreciate any guidance.

Comment: The Flatten layer squeezes the dimensions of the output of Conv2D. This flattened vector is then passed to the Dense layers.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but how come it produces different result every time when I run? I need the flatten layer even when I only use dense layer because my input layer accepts pictures (multi-dimensional data). Input> flatten > dense produces consistent result, but input > conv2d > flatten > dense produces different result every time I run the code.